# Mostrar datos de una tabla SQL SERVER en HTML/PHP

Tags: javascript, html5, php7

estoy haciendo una pagina con formulario para consultar polizas, pero como puedo hacer que la conexión al servidor en la nube funcione ya que he visto otros metodos y no me sirven ya que son en MYSQL y la consulta es en SQL SERVER con la consulta siguiente, al momento de pulsar el boton toma los datos de los inputs para cambiar el valor de Serie y/o Cliente en la consulta y arrojar los datos en los otros inputs:

```
select FolioPoliza, Status as Estado from Polizas where Serie = 'AHO' or Cliente = 'Victor';
```

todo mi código HTML/PHP es el siguiente(tengan en cuenta que del form sa van a usar SERIE y CLIENTE para la consulta del query):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/responsivo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="consulta_poliza">
       <form action="" method="post">
           <label for="">Serie:</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="Serie" class="Texto" placeholder="Ingrese serie de poliza">
           <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Consultar" onclick="
              var valor1 = document.getElementById('Serie').value;
              var valor2 = document.getElementById('Cliente').value;">
           <br>
           <label for="">Cliente:</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="Pol_Cliente" class="Texto" placeholder="Nombre del Cliente">
           <br>
           <label for="">Folio Poliza:</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="FOL_Numero" class="Texto" disabled="disabled">
           <label for="">Estado:</label>
           <input type="text" name="" id="POL_Estado" class="Texto" disabled="disabled">
           <label for="">Nota:(A)-Poliza Activa (B)-Poliza dada de baja</label>
       </form>
    </section>
    <?php
        function conectar()
        {
            $x = new sqlsrv(
                "Direción IP",
                "User", "ABC.12345!", "B. Datos"
            )
            if($x->connection_aborted)
            {
                die("Error: ".$x->sqlsrv_connect_errno().$x->sqlsrv_connect:error());
                exit;
            }
            return $x;
        }
    ?>">
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Formulario de consulta]

Comment: Si esta ahí colega, justo donde dice la dirección IP, pero este metodo que consegui es para mysql, no me funciono con sql server

Comment: Si estuvieras más familiarizado con PDO (siglas de PHP Data Objects) fuera posible (y relativamente fácil) lograr una conexión SQL Server mediante PHP. PDO viene por defecto listo para implementar conexiones MySQL y PostgreSQL (que son los que he usado), pero no para SQL Server. Aunque puedes descargar el archivo que hace posible esto (es un dll) desde el sitio web de Microsoft totalmente gratis. Incluso te muestran en qué ruta de tu equipo debes copiarlo y lo que debes agregar en el archivo php.ini para hacerlo funcionar. Esto lo probé hace un tiempo y realmente funciona, te lo garantizo. Apa

Answer (score 0):

- Solo para aclarar lo que dice **@Guillermo Vidal** Claro que es posible trabajar con **PHP** y **SQLserver** hace tiempo realice un proyecto donde específicamente tenían **SQLserver** y toda la lógica de negocios estaba realizada con **PHP**.
- Te dejo algunos enlaces que te ayudarán a realizar conexiones a bases de datos SQLserver provenientes de la propia documentacion de PHP que en su tiempo me sirvieron de mucho.

Enlace 1:

[sqlsrv_fetch - Manual - PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php)

Ejemplo practico:

[Otro ejemplo de conexion a SQLserver](https://www.elielaguilera.com/2012/06/viernes-de-sql-server/)

- Si continuas leyendo lo que tu buscas es **sqlsrv_fetch_array()** que convierte los registros de una tabla en un **array** haciendo esto ya podras mostrarlos en donde sea, claro recorriendo el array de la manera correcta, te dejo un ejemplo:

[sqlsrv_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)